# How do I insert values into a table with a column-wise uniqueness check?

Tags: sql

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table`
(
    id Uint64,
    name String,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Insert values

```
INSERT INTO `my_table`
    ( id, name )
VALUES (1, 'name1'),
       (2, 'name2'),
       (3, 'name3');
```

| # | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | "name1" |
| 1 | 2 | "name2" |
| 2 | 3 | "name3" |

How add VALUES (4, 'name1') and skip add VALUES (3, 'name1')?

The available syntax is described here: https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/ydb/yql/reference/syntax/insert_into

Comment: It sounds like you want `id` to be unique.  And your table already does that.

Comment: If I insert VALUES (3, 'name1') then I get the error `Operation aborted due to constraint violation: insert_pk`

Comment: do you have to insert them with using VALUES?

Comment: Yes, I am adding a new value and I don’t know if it is in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation link that you provided in the comments I see that the databse that you use does not support a statement equivalent to `INSERT OR IGNORE...` to suppress errors if a unique constraint is violated.

As an alternative you can use `INSERT ... SELECT`.

If your database supports `EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT 3, 'name1'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 3);
```

Or you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT t.id, t.name
FROM (SELECT 3 AS id, 'name1' AS name) AS t
LEFT JOIN my_table AS m 
ON m.id = t.id
WHERE m.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: ```EXISTS``` not supported
```LEFT JOIN``` what i was looking for just couldn't write correctly